# If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, which is bigger, $\sigma(n^2)/n^2$ or $\sigma(n)/q^k$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

**QUESTION**

> If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, which is bigger, $\sigma(n^2)/n^2$ or $\sigma(n)/q^k$?

**BACKGROUND**

If $\sigma(N)=2N$ (where $\sigma(N)$ is the *sum of the divisors* of $N$), then $N$ is said to be *perfect*. (Denote the *abundancy index* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.)

Euler proved that every odd perfect number has the form $N=q^k n^2$, where $q$ is prime (called the *Euler prime*) satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

**MY ATTEMPT TO ANSWER THE QUESTION**

Let $N=q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$.

Suppose that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}=\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}.$$

Then
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}<2=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
so that $q^k < n$.

Additionally,
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}=\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
implies that
$${q^k}\sigma(n^2) = {n^2}\sigma(n).$$
Therefore, $n^2 \mid {q^k}\sigma(n^2)$ and $q^k \mid {n^2}\sigma(n)$.  Since $\gcd(q,n)=\gcd(q^k, n^2)=1$, then $n^2 \mid \sigma(n^2)$ and $q^k \mid \sigma(n)$.  This implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}=\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}$$
is an integer, contradicting
$$1 < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} < 2.$$
(In fact, we have the stronger bound $8/5 < \sigma(n^2)/n^2$.)

Consequently,
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} \neq \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}.$$

Therefore, we either have
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} < 2$$
or
$$\frac{8}{5} < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}.$$

The second case implies $q^k < n$ since
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}.$$

The first case implies
$$n < {2^{\frac{\ln(12/13)}{\ln(9/13)}}}\cdot{(q^k)^{(\frac{\ln(13/12)}{\ln(13/9)}+\ln(13/9))}} \approx (1.162854)\cdot(q^k)^{0.5853949291}$$
if we use the estimate
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} < \bigg(\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(13/9)}{\ln(4/3)}}.$$
Note that the inequality
$$n < {2^{\frac{\ln(12/13)}{\ln(9/13)}}}\cdot{(q^k)^{(\frac{\ln(13/12)}{\ln(13/9)}+\ln(13/9))}} \approx (1.162854)\cdot(q^k)^{0.5853949291}$$
**almost violates** the inequality $q^k < n^2$.

**References**

> 1. [The Abundancy Index of Divisors of Odd Perfect Numbers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf)
> 2. [The Abundancy Index of Divisors of Odd Perfect Numbers - Part II](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0906.pdf)